# Stripe stopped working after migrating to heroku

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I just migrated to heroku and when I try to charge a customer I get this error.

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Stripe: Unknown arguments ([object Object]). Did you mean to pass an options object? See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Passing-Options.
```

Below is my cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("charge", function(request, response){
Stripe.charges.create({
amount: 100*100,
currency: "usd",
customer: request.params.customerId,
card: request.params.cardId
},{
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    response.success("success");
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    response.error(httpResponse)
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Do you have all your libraries installed.

Comment: Yes I can perform other stripe functions, it's just charging that is giving me this error.

Comment: Odd. Are you sure your stack trace is indicating that this code is the issue? Also, is this your exact code, or have you modified anything before pasting into SO?

Comment: `2016-08-14T05:22:15.382882+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled rejection Error: Stripe: Unknown arguments ([object Object]). Did you mean to pass an options object? See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Passing-Options. (on API request to POST function (outputs) {
2016-08-14T05:22:15.382895+00:00 app[web.1]:        return cleanString.replace(/\{([\s\S]+?)\}/g, function($0, $1) {
2016-08-14T05:22:15.382896+00:00 app[web.1]:           return encodeURIComponent(outputs[$1] || '');
2016-08-14T05:22:15.382898+00:00 app[web.1]:         });
2016-08-14T05:22:15.382898+00:00 app[web.1]:       })`

Comment: Haven't modified anything

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're no longer on Parse's cloud code thus you no longer have access to Parse's Stripe library. Now you're using the real Stripe library which does not take parameters like that.

The Stripe library uses standard node callbacks like:

```
Stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 100*100,
  currency: "usd",
  customer: request.params.customerId,
  card: request.params.cardId
}, function(error, charge) {
  // do something
});
```